# Mysterious crash in iOS 9: -[SKTAppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, crash

I got a crash report after exercising my app from Crashlytics. I tooks like this:

[image]

The full stacktrace as given looks like this:

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 578074103 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                807402615 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 578095805 __methodDescriptionForSelector
3  CoreFoundation                 578086961 ___forwarding___
4  CoreFoundation                 577239944 _CF_forwarding_prep_0
5  MakeEatSee                     2151151 didReceiveLocalNotificationNewImpl
6  UIKit                          635813433 -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:]
7  UIKit                          635780589 -[UIApplication workspace:didReceiveActions:]
8  FrontBoardServices             686207177 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke
9  CoreFoundation                 577839101 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
10 CoreFoundation                 577835713 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks
11 CoreFoundation                 577830427 __CFRunLoopRun
12 CoreFoundation                 577096497 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
13 CoreFoundation                 577096003 CFRunLoopRunInMode
14 GraphicsServices               698237009 GSEventRunModal
15 UIKit                          633677553 UIApplicationMain
16 MakeEatSee                     502059 main (main.m:14)
17 libdyld.dylib                  813284015 start
```

`MakeEatSee` is the name of my app. This happened around the time a `NSNotification` got posted.
I've tested this codepath before, and it's definitely worked before.

I can't make sense of this crash. Reasons being:

1. There's no mentions of `SKTAppDelegate` anywhere in the stack trace.
2. There's no `SKTAppDelegate` in the codebase, as far as I know. `SKT` prefix is usually for SupportKit, the old name for Smooch. This, I do use in the app. But there's no , which I do use in the app.
3. The only mention of `SKTAppDelegate` leads you to some [Apple demo sources](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/Sketch/Listings/SKTAppDelegate_m.html)
4. There is no `didReceiveLocalNotificationNewImpl` method in my app.

Why did this crash happen? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: The stack says that `didReceiveLocalNotificationNewImpl` is part of your code (frame #5).  What's in there?

Comment: Update your question with your `didReceiveLocalNotificationNewImpl` method.

Comment: And symbolicate the crash report so you can see exactly where in your app it is crashing.

Comment: Hi @PhillipMills and rmaddy thanks for your responses. There's no didReceiveLocalNotificationNewImpl in my app. I've just updated the question with this weirdness.

When I export and symolicate the crash report I get the same thing as Crashlytics is giving me — i.e. there are no line numbers or anything.

Comment: Build your app with Write Link Map File enabled in the build settings (if you don't already).  Search for that symbol in the map; it should show you a module number in square brackets where the symbol is defined.  Then look for that module number at the start of the map to get the module name.

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks, it does appear that this is an issue relating to the Smooch SDK. I think there's some level of method swizzling that's make .  I'm amazed — I've been using Xcode / developing iOS apps for so long and have never heard of the  `Write Link Map File` option.

The fun part is to see how I can keep using their SDK and avoid the crash.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this is caused by using Smooch iOS SDK 3.0.0. I have updated to the latest version 3.0.1 and this problem appears to have been resolved.